# RIA Services does not support entities that are decorated by NHibernate mapping attributes?

Tags: silverlight, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, wcf-ria-services

I'm working on a project where entities are being decorated by NHibernate mapping attributes such as [Property] and [Class]. Unfortunately RIAServices doesn't seem to support most of these attributes, which causes a failure when RIAServices is trying to generate the Silverlight Client Code.

When I try to build a DomainService that uses an entity decorated with the [Class] or [Property] attribute, I get an ArgumentNullException with the following error message:

```
Error   2   The "CreateRiaClientFilesTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: TypeName
at System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)
at NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.ClassAttribute.get_NameType()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.StandardCustomAttributeBuilder.GetPropertyValues(IEnumerable`1 propertyMaps, Attribute attribute)
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.StandardCustomAttributeBuilder.GetAttributeDeclaration(Attribute attribute)
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.CustomAttributeGenerator.GenerateCustomAttributes(ClientProxyGenerator proxyGenerator, CodeTypeDeclaration referencingType, IEnumerable`1 attributes, CodeCommentStatementCollection comments)
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.CustomAttributeGenerator.GenerateCustomAttributes(ClientProxyGenerator proxyGenerator, CodeTypeDeclaration referencingType, IEnumerable`1 attributes, CodeAttributeDeclarationCollection outputCollection, CodeCommentStatementCollection comments)
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.EntityProxyGenerator.Generate()
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.ClientProxyGenerator.GenerateProxyClass(String& generatedCode)
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.CreateRiaClientFilesTask.GenerateClientProxies()
at System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.CreateRiaClientFilesTask.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)  SL
```

I know that using Fluent NHibernate should solve the problem because it removes the need for NHibernate dependencies, but I want to make sure first that there aren't any other solutions before moving to Fluent NHibernate. Any thoughts on solving this problem?

Comment: Looks like that exception is coming from the NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.ClassAttribute class on the NameType property, not from RIA Services.

Comment: The NHibernate Mapping Attributes are indeed causing the exceptions. If I remove the [Class] attribute then the [Property] attributes are causing the same exception, this time it starts at "NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.PropertyAttribute.get_AccessType()". I'm finding it difficult to see where the problem lies because 
I can't debug clientcode generation(?). It seems like RIAServices doesn't support all the NH mapping attributes, despite they are serializable. The attributes don't cause problems in the rest of the application.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments it sounds like the issue is with NHibernate throwing up during the code generation. If you really want to use the attributes I would suggest getting the NHibernate source code and trying to attach the VS debugger to the VS instance that is doing the code generation, might help you figure out why it is failing.

Probably a better approach would be to follow [this post by Brada on using NHibernate with RIA Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/08/06/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-nhibernate.aspx) or [watching this screencast on NHibernate with RIA Services](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2009/07/13/aspnet-mvc-dynamicdata-domain-riaservices-unity-and-nhibernate-part-1/). Both of those places seem to have working examples of them working together, so maybe start there instead of going down the route you're going.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to attach the VS debugger to the VS instance that is doing the code generation. I know the posts you mentioned and in both posts they apply a different (better) way of mapping, but before switching to Fluent NHibernate (which takes a lot of time in my situation) I want to make sure it's not possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can add preprocessor directives to your entities so that when compiled for silverlight the attributes are missing.

```
#if SILVERLIGHT
//nothing
#else
[class]
#endif
public class entity{
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, but unfortunately this doesn't work either because it still tries to use the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.  Solution:  Get rid of the attributes and just use XML for mapping.

Comment: That is indeed a solution, I prefer to use FuentNHibernate with automapping